# How to evaluate sums of the form $\sum_{i=a}^b f(i)g(i)$

Tags: summation, discrete-calculus

$$\sum_{i=a}^b f(i)g(i)$$

Where $f$ and $g$ aren't constant. I know this might be very broad, but all I'm looking for is to be pointed in the direction of theorems/disciplines that deal with this. Anything, like a rule that states I can move the components around in a specific way, which might be a more helpful reformulation.

In my case, I know what $\displaystyle \sum_{i=a}^b f(i)$ is, and I know what $\displaystyle 
 \sum_{i=a}^b g(i)$ is. A rule that relates their respective values to the value of the above formula would definitively provide a solution for me.

Comment: Summation by parts?

Comment: @fwd Could you elaborate your question?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts

Comment: @fwd Yes, the Abel transformation seems to be what I'm looking for! Thank you!

Comment: @fwd If you make your comment into an answer, I will accept it. If not, I'll just provide an answer myself a little later. It was the Abel transformation that I was looking for. Tested it, and it gave the right answer for me!